# Get Annotated Tags from revwalk commit

Tags: c, libgit2

I want to go through repository logs including tags. So far I can print out all SHA for all commits including tags with revwalk. However, each time I want to pull the tag information using the commit oid I get error

> "The requested type does not match the type in ODB"

I can see that the tag SHA reported by revwalk contains the SHA reported by `git show-ref --tags` So I don't know why tag lookup does not work.

Here is the simplified code that I use:

```
int error = 0;
git_oid oid;

git_revwalk *walk;
error = git_revwalk_new(&walk, m_repo);  

git_revwalk_sorting(walk,
                    GIT_SORT_TOPOLOGICAL |
                    GIT_SORT_TIME);

git_revwalk_push_head(walk);
//git_revwalk_hide_glob(walk, "tags/*"); -- I want to see tags so I commented this one 

while(git_revwalk_next(&oid, walk) == 0)
{
    git_commit *commit;
    char oidstr[10] = {0};

    if(git_commit_lookup(&commit, m_repo, &oid)==0)
    {

        git_tag *tag = NULL;
        int error = git_tag_lookup(&tag, m_repo, &oid);
        if(error==0)
        {
            wxString tname(git_tag_name(tag));
            data.push_back("["+tname+"] "+cltStr);
        }
        else
        {
            //It always land here with error no -3 and message: The requested type does not match the type in ODB
        }

        git_tag_free(tag);

        const git_signature *author = git_commit_author(commit); 
    }
    git_commit_free(commit);
}
git_revwalk_free(walk);
```

TL;DR

When I have git_tag object I can get the target commit. Now I have the target commit, so how do I get the tag(s) under that commit? Something similar to `git tag --points-at commit_SHA`

**UPDATE**

After Carlos' answer here is my new code. The challenge now is how do I get the git_tag*. As you can see I have git_reference* (named ref) but I don't know how to convert it to git_tag*

```
git_reference_iterator *iter = NULL;
git_reference *ref = NULL;

git_reference_iterator_glob_new(&iter, m_repo, "refs/tags/*");

while(git_reference_next(&ref, iter) == 0)
{
    git_object *target = NULL;
    git_object *obj;

    const git_oid *targetId = git_reference_target(ref);
    git_object_lookup(&obj, m_repo, targetId, GIT_OBJ_ANY);

    git_object_peel(&target, obj, GIT_OBJ_COMMIT);

    if(git_oid_equal(git_commit_id(commit), git_commit_id((git_commit*)target))==1)
    {
        //tag found
        //how do I get a git_tag* here? 
    } 
    git_object_free(obj);
    git_reference_free(ref);
    git_object_free(target); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annotated tag is its own object, which exists as a root of the object graph. I.E. they point to objects, but nothing points to them[0] so if you want to figure out the reverse mapping you need to keep the list yourself. This is what `git tag --points-at`'s reverse mapping does: take a list of tags and what they point to and then look up in that list for the id you're interested in.

With libgit2, you can do this by using a reference iterator to look over anything under `refs/tags/` (`git_reference_iterator_glob_new(&iter, repo, "refs/tags/*"))` and take the reference's target (`git_reference_target()`), use `git_object_peel()` to get to the commit (or any other object type you're interested in) and then compare that object's id with the one you're looking for.

As far as the code in the question goes, `git_tag_lookup`, like every other object lookup function, looks up the annotated tag you ask it to (a `git_tag` object). If you pass in a commit's id, then it will load that commit and see that the types don't match and give this error.

[0] Although tags can point to other tags, that's not relevant to this case

**UPDATE**

What the updated code needs is to do what you were doing before. Use `git_tag_lookup()` to look up a `git_tag` object and pass in the reference target as the id to look up. But we aware that not all tag references will point to a tag objects. In many projects, tags point to the commits directly.

You can use `git_object_peel()` again to try to get a tag (`GIT_OBJ_TAG`) which will return an error if there is no annotated tag.

But you should also note if you're trying to replicate `git tag --points-at` that it doesn't care whether there are annotated tags in the chain. As long as a particular tag reference can be resolved to the commit you give it, it'll return that result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. Now I can see. However can you explain what exactly peel does? I have tried to understand it from docs (in all those days I have been fighting this issue) but I couldn't get it into my brain. Again thank you!

Comment: I have tried to make sense of the excellent explanation but so far I have not been able to. Can you write simple untested example just to illustrate your points? I cannot combine them to get what I want.

Comment: I have tried to apply your comments now I have new code and challenge, Please see updated post. Thanks